# Postgresql - Preserve relative position when using distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I ran a query which returned a table like this.

```
 d |  e  | f  
---+-----+----
 2 | 103 | C
 6 | 201 | AB
 1 | 102 | B
 1 | 102 | B
 1 | 102 | B
 1 | 102 | B
 1 | 102 | B
 3 | 105 | E
 3 | 105 | E
 3 | 105 | E
```

What I want is to get distinct rows but in order. Basically I want this:

```
2 | 103 | C
6 | 201 | AB
1 | 102 | B
3 | 105 | E
```

I tried `distinct` and `group by`, but they are not always preserving the position (they preserved it for some other cases that I had). Any idea as to how can this be done easily or would one need to use other functionalities like `rank`?

Comment: Distinct on *what*? ORDER BY *what* ? Preserving *which* position?

Comment: @wildplasser Basically we can boil this to a single column as well which contains, say, numbers like 1,1,1,8,8,5,6,6. And output would be 1,8,5,6. Does this clarify?

Comment: @Miraj50 . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets. There is no ordering unless a column specifies the ordering -- and none of your columns do.

Comment: probably answer is: "need to use other functionalities like rank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless you have an explicit `order by` with a column or expression.

If you have such an ordering, you can do what you want using `group by`:

```
select d, e, f
from t
group by d, e, f
order by min(a);  -- assuming a is the column that specifies the ordering
```

Answer (score 1):

Use case when:

```
order by case when f=C then 1 when f=AB then 2
when f=B then 3 when f=E then 5 else null end
```

Comment: But isn't this making it hard-coded? My question is general. I believe this answer will work only for this case.

Comment: when you want.customize order then you have to use some rules

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `order by` [ctid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) column, which describes the physical location of a row, to identify a row.

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

use `row_number` with *windows function* to make row number by `ctid`.

then get `rn = 1` and `order by ctid`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  d int,
  e int,
  f varchar(5)
);

insert into t values (2,103, 'C');
insert into t values (6,201, 'AB');
insert into t values (1,102, 'B');
insert into t values (1,102, 'B');
insert into t values (1,102, 'B');
insert into t values (1,102, 'B');
insert into t values (1,102, 'B');
insert into t values (3,105, 'E');
insert into t values (3,105, 'E');
insert into t values (3,105, 'E');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select d,e,f 
from (
  select d,e,f,ctid,row_number() over(partition by d,e,f order by ctid) rn
  FROM T
)t1
where rn = 1
order by ctid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e290/21/0)**:

```
| d |   e |  f |
|---|-----|----|
| 2 | 103 |  C |
| 6 | 201 | AB |
| 1 | 102 |  B |
| 3 | 105 |  E |
```